# What is slowing my website down in safari?

Tags: javascript, performance, debugging, browser, safari

I hope this question is allowed on stackoverflow,

I'm building my stepmom a new website for her business (please keep in mind this is still a work in progress) and it runs fine in chrome and firefox, but it's extremely slow and laggy in safari.

I've sent the url to a couple of friends just to make sure its not my browser or machine.

The 2 pages that seem to be the slowest are the 'services' page and the 'FAQ' page, I'm fairly certain the sliders are not the issue, since they run just fine in an empty page. There's also alot of unused CSS at the moment, which I will get around to cleaning up, but I don't think thats the issue either (I could be wrong) since the other pages seem to run OK.

Please keep in mind that I'm somewhat of a beginner, and I'm not looking for anyone to fix the issue for me. I'm just hoping someone can point me in the right direction. And if this type of question isn't allowed, please let me know so I can delete it.

https://secure-hollows-07774.herokuapp.com/

Comment: can you describe in what way it feels laggy?

Comment: See [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/4642212) — in short: no.

Comment: @yifansong sure, the entire pages skips as you scroll, and the animations are either super choppy or don't execute at all.

Comment: Your issue with lag is caused by how you handle your animations. When you scroll you change `translate` etc. for every scroll event that is fired (which is fired for every pixel movement). For example, you have a delay of 0.6 seconds on the main background (green shape that moves left as you scroll). When you change the translate every 0.1 seconds due to scrolling you queue up a load of animations to happen that all overlap and this causes lag. If you throttle the scroll rate to match you animation speed it will fix the issue. I would go with 0.3s throttle and 0.3s animation to make it smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are two reasons why this might be happening:**

1. Clear your browser cache. I just checked it out on my MBP Mid-2012, it was slow to load on Safari, but it is definitely faster when I'm trying to use it on an Incognito window (Private Mode). In order to solve this, you can try using **memcached** or something similar.
2. A less likely reason might be this thing with Heroku where your applications get unloaded when out of use in for extended periods of time in order to free up server memory. This might have something to do with it as well. If this is causing the issue, you can try to increase your dynos.